# Rules with exceptions in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule that redirects from `http://localhost/username` to `http://localhost/profile_redirect.php?user=username`

The htaccess rule for this is

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

# when user name != directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ profile_redirect.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

# when user name == directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ profile_redirect.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Is it possible to have exceptions for this rule? For example, I have a page that has the url `http://localhost/members` , so when using that URL, due to the .htaccess rule, it redirects to `http://localhost/profile_redirect.php?user=members`, which shouldn't happen.

I have only 3 such exceptions to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

# ignore these paths for further rewriting
RewriteRule ^(members|exception1|exception2)(/|$) - [NC,L]

# when user name != directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ profile_redirect.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

# when user name == directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ profile_redirect.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```